# Android: BroadcastListner Getting error

Tags: android, android-networking, android-broadcast

In my app, I am continuously checking for internet connection. If there is no internet at any point of time, the user gets a toast message.

For this I am making a `NetworkStateReceiver` class that extends the `BroadcastReceiver` class.

Java file:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent); // Here I'm getting the error mentioned below
        Log.d("app", "Network connectivity change");
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            NetworkInfo ni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                Log.i("app", "Network " + ni.getTypeName() + " connected");
            }
        }
        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean(
                ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.d("app", "There's no network connectivity");
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

> Cannot directly invoke  the abstract method onReceive(Context, Intent) for the type BroadcastReceiver

This is what I've put in my Android manifest file inside application:

```
<application>    
    ....
    <receiver android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ....
</application>
```

This is the permission I've used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

Why am I getting this error in `super.onReceive(context, intent);`, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: You haven't told us the error you are getting. Post a stack trace from your Logcat if your program is crashing, or tell us what behavior you are observing versus what you are expecting.

Comment: @Karakuri it isn't a runtime error, it's the error i am getting at the line in which  super.onReceive(context, intent); is written in java file.

Comment: @Karakuri No it isn't working. I am not able to see the log file output when the connectivity state is changed.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the line `super.onReceive(context, intent)`. The base implementation does nothing anyway (it's an abstract method).